# Frame for " " will be different at run time in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard

I have view item and shows me warning under below:

> Frame for "myView" will be different at run time.

How can i resolve it ?

[image]

Comment: You have to solve this by setting up your constraints correctly in IB.

Comment: @nhgrif after i got that warning

Comment: @nhgrif question cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constraints are probably set correctly, since you're getting just a warning.

1. Go to your Storyboard an look in your Document Outline for the yellow triangle
   [image: Document Outliner warning]
2. Click on it so that it displays all Misplaced views
   [image: Show misplaced views]
3. Make sure that Update frames is selected and click fix misplacement (you can also check the "Apply to all views in container" if you have lot of misplaced views and want to reposition it in single click)
   [image: Update frames]